# Changes does not appear immediately on front page in drupal

Tags: drupal

I'm new to drupal. There is a client website that we do some changes by using admin panel.

Changing some text in some pages. But the changes does not appear if you are not logged as admin or the user who made the changes.

after one day you can see that the changes can be seen by not logged users as well.

I search for cache problems or permission problems but I could not find anything in google.

What do you think is this?

not: cleaning browser cache or ctrl+f5 won't work.

Comment: Please specify what Drupal version you are on. And review the cache settings (admin/config/performance or admin/config/development/performance) for your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If page caching for anonymous users is enabled, those visitors will see a cached version (and not the latest modified version).

Depending your configuration, this caching (minimum cache lifetime) can be between 1 minute and 24 hours. To verify / change your settings go to `admin/config/performance`.